# How do I resolve dependency conflicts with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am developing a project with Dropwizard and Titan DB. Both depend on Google Guava. One depends on version 15 and the other on 18. This error occurs at runtime:

```
! java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool$ID
BlockRunnable
```

I researched the error and [found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/vQ90mchs62s) that it was being caused by titan's Guava 
15.0 dependency being evicted by Guava 18.0.

I am new to Java and Gradle. I am using Gradle's `java` and `application` plugins to build and run the main class with `gradle run`. How can  I resolve this problem?

---

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.example.rest.App"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile (
        [group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-core', version: '0.8.0-rc1'],
        [group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-core', version: '0.5.1'],
        [group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-berkeleyje', version: '0.5.1'],
        [group: 'com.tinkerpop', name: 'frames', version: '2.6.0']
    )
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '3.8.1'
}

run {  
    if ( project.hasProperty("appArgs") ) {  
        args Eval.me(appArgs)  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not build fat jars for running/testing, if possible. I am currently in the process of reading http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html.

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @fge Just put that up. The more I read dependency_management.html, the more it seems like I need to keep reading that page.

Comment: To date, I think this is the best description of how how to handle this problem that I've found: https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade

Answer (score 9):

By default, Gradle will select the highest version for a dependency when there's a conflict.  You can force a particular version to be used with a custom resolutionStrategy (adapted from http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html):

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
  }
}
```

This doesn't add a dependency on guava 15.0, but says if there is a dependency (even transitively) to force the use of 15.0.

You can get more information on where your dependencies come from with `gradle dependencies` and `gradle dependencyInsight ...`.

FYI, it looks like you have a few different versions of Guava requested (11.0.2, 14.0.1, 15.0 and 18.0).

HTH

Comment: Thanks bigguy. I come to Java from Node.js, where npm and the runtime path resolution mechanism makes managing transitive properties trivial. Is there a way I can emulate this sort of thing in Java? Is that called shading?

Comment: Yes, shading transforms all of the class names from a dependency so they won't conflict (but you can then have many duplicate classes).  OSGi has similar goals (runtime resolution of dependencies and separate classloaders).

Comment: Thanks, will look into OSGi too. Is the main concern with duplicates the enlarged memory footprint of your application? I think that running with exact declared dependency versions is usually more significant than RAM usage?

Comment: Older JVMs used to have a separate memory space for loaded classes (PermGen), so you could run out of memory.  Since JDK8, that's gone. Shading wouldn't work if you had a dependency on a third-party class in your external interface.  That would force users of your API to use the same version as you.

Comment: Thanks bigguy. I still haven't read about shading, so maybe it will be obvious when I do, but why would shading introduce that problem to my library? Would that be resolvable by the client shading, too?

Comment: Shading is a post processing step that changes the bytecode of class files to rename classes and create private copies of bytecode.  So if you used com.thirdparty.Foo in your external interface, shaded it to my.copy.com.thirdparty.Foo, clients would need to use the class my.copy.com.thirdparty.Foo instead of com.thirdparty.Foo.  That's why shading is usually only limited to internal dependencies.