# How library conflicts are resolved inside Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Suppose I have a library called `my-library` and it's using `lib1`'s version `X` to get `methodX`.

Now if the `app` is using version `Y` of `lib1`, (that doesn't have `methodX` (removed)), How is the build system (or compiler?) going to resolve this issue? Would it throw a build error? If yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: If `lib1` comes with its own dependency requirements, then it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @JinesiYelizati Any idea how the dex will handle this? (given they are using the same package name). The compiler will merge `X` and `Y` and put it into same dir?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve dependency conflicts with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004899/how-do-i-resolve-dependency-conflicts-with-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

1# Failed if there is confliction

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}
```

2# force figer out certain version

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        'com.yourgroup:yourlib:yourversion'
    }
}
```